# Error Trying to get property 'cantidad' of non-object al mostrar un registro en Datatable a partir de una relación laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

Tengo un datatable con la Tabla **Articulos** donde muestro la descripción del articulo (hasta ahi todo bién) ahora lo que necesito en ese mismo datatable  es  mostrar en la columna cantidad los registros de la columna cantidad  de la tabla **Inventario** la cual tengo hecho una relación mediante la columna articulos_id de la tabla inventario y la columna id de la tabla articulos.

**Modelo Articulos (Relación)**

```
public function inventarios() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Inventario');
    }
```

**Modelo Inventario (Relación)**

```
public function articulo() {

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Articulo');
    }
```

**Controller**

```
return Datatables::of(Articulo::all())

        ->addColumn('cantidad',function($articulo){
           return  $articulo->inventario->cantidad;

        })


        ->addColumn('acciones',function($articulo){
            TODO: enviar botones segun permisos
            return Controller::get_actions_buttons(
                NULL,
                route('articulos.edit',$articulo->id),
                route('articulos.update',$articulo->id),
                'articulo',

            );
        })
        ->rawColumns(['acciones'])
        ->make(true);
```

Comment: La relación se llama `inventarios` y no `inventario`. por lo tanto para acceder deberás escribir `$articulo->inventarios` en vez de `$articulo->inventario`. Además es `hasMany`, por lo tanto te va a devolver una colección de objetos `Inventario`, entonces deberás iterar sobre esa colección para acceder a algún atributo de cada objeto, salvo que quieras simplemente sumar las cantidades.

Answer (score 0):

Proba agregandole la foreign key al belongsTo
`public function articulo() {

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Articulo', 'foreign_key');
}`
```

Comment: Sigo con el mismo error, creo recordar que habia que crear una funcion getNombre y convertir en objetos cantidad pero no tengo muy claro como se hace eso

Comment: Si queres crear una funcion getNombre Y setNombre debes hacerlo en el controlador de Inventario public function

Comment: `public function getNombre(){ return this.nombre }` public function setNombre($nombre) { this.nombre = $nombre }